# How to use MutableLiveData in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, retrofit, android-livedata

I'm using an MVVM architecture in Kotlin. I have created a ViewModel and Repository class. In Repository class I'm fetching data from API using a retrofit. I'm storing that data into my MutableLiveData object, but while debugging the object is always showing null even if my response.body is not null.

I'm very new to Kotlin.
Please help..

**ItemRepository.kt**

```
   class ItemRepository {

    companion object{
        private var instance: ItemRepository? = null
        private  var itemMutableList: MutableLiveData<List<ItemItem>>? = null

         fun getinstance(): ItemRepository {
            if (instance == null){
                instance = ItemRepository()
            }

            return instance as ItemRepository
        }
    }

    fun getItems() :MutableLiveData<List<ItemItem>>?{
        var itemCall : Call<List<ItemItem>?> = ApiClient.getInstance()!!.getApi()!!.getIteams();

        itemCall.enqueue(object : Callback<List<ItemItem>?> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<ItemItem>?>, t: Throwable) {

            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<ItemItem>?>, response: Response<List<ItemItem>?>) {
                var itemItem = response.body()

               itemMutableList?.value = itemItem
                itemMutableList // showing null value
            }

        })
        return itemMutableList
    }
}
```

**MainViewModel.kt**

```
 class MainViewModel : ViewModel {

    private var itemMutableList : MutableLiveData<List<ItemItem>>? = null
    private var itemRepository: ItemRepository? = null


    constructor()
    {
        if(itemMutableList != null){
            return
        }
        itemRepository = ItemRepository.getinstance()
        itemMutableList = itemRepository?.getItems()
    }

    fun getResultList() : MutableLiveData<List<ItemItem>>? {

        if(itemMutableList != null)
        {
            itemMutableList
        }
        return  itemMutableList
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
  class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var mainViewModel: MainViewModel? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        mainViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

        mainViewModel?.getResultList()?.observe(this, Observer { itmList ->


        })

    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You have not initialized itemMutableList. That is why you are getting null.

```
private  var itemMutableList: MutableLiveData<List<ItemItem>> = MutableLiveData()
```

Now in your response function assign value to it:

```
override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<ItemItem>?>, response: Response<List<ItemItem>?>) {
                var itemItem = response.body()

               itemMutableList.postValue(itemItem)
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it.